# How to set format for datetime and date in sonata admin filters symfony2

Tags: symfony, datetime-format, sonata-admin

How to set the datetime or date filters in sonata admin datagridfilters?

I want to do the following for the sonata admin filters, which works for edit form

```
->add('createdAt', 'datetime', array('label' => 'Created at', 'disabled' => true, 
                  'input' => 'datetime',
                  'date_widget' => 'choice',
                  'time_widget' => 'choice',
                  'date_format' => 'MMM d, y',))

->add('deadline', 'date', array('label' => 'Deadline', 'disabled' => true, 
                  'input' => 'datetime',
                  'widget' => 'choice',
                  'format' => 'MMM d, y'))
```

but it does not work (or the options are ignored) when used in filters using doctrine_orm_date and doctrine_orm_datetime

```
->add('createdAt', 'doctrine_orm_datetime', array('label' => 'Created At',
                'input' => 'datetime',
                  'date_widget' => 'choice',
                  'time_widget' => 'choice',
                  'date_format' => 'MMM d, y'))

->add('deadline', 'doctrine_orm_date', array('label' => 'Deadline',
                'input' => 'datetime',
                  'widget' => 'choice',
                  'format' => 'MMM d, y'))
```

The reason that I am forced to do this is because, on my server (centos 5.2, php 5.3.20) the month field is being rendered as timestamp but on my dev machine it is rendered perfectly - there are a few questions regarding this issue but no real fix. These 2 links describe my problem main problem - e.g. [symfony2 - date choice input renders timestamp instead of month name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13879604/symfony2-date-choice-input-renders-timestamp-instead-of-month-name),
http://iqwen.net/question/155068

so I would like to know 3 things

1. how to set the format option for datetime / date fields in the sonata admin filters
2. Is there a way to fix the issue where month appears as timestamp on linux env
3. How can i set a global format option for date / datetime field in symfony2 / sonata admin so that I do not have to specify the format next to each field

Any help regarding wiill be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10433153/1553481) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16289056/1553481).

Comment: after i updated the vendor bundles to 2.2, this issue resolved itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way:

```
->add('createdAt', 'doctrine_orm_callback', 
              array(
                'label' => 'Created At',
                'callback' => function($queryBuilder, $alias, $field, $value) {
                                if (!$value['value']) {
                                    return;
                                }
                                $time = strtotime($value['value']);
                                $inputValue = date('Y-m-d', $time);
                                $queryBuilder->andWhere("DATE($alias.createdAt) <= :CreatedAt");
                                $queryBuilder->setParameter('CreatedAt', $inputValue);
                                return true;
                              },
                'field_type' => 'text'
              ), null, array('attr' => array('class' => 'datepicker')))
```

The DATE function is a cast that you define with DQL.